# "Login As" feature visibility

Tags: commcare

What determines whether the "Login As" option shows up for a (mobile) user when they log into CommCare HQ and are on the Web Apps page?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things that a user must have in order for them to be able to use the Login As feature on web apps:

1. They have to have the "Edit Mobile Workers" permission
2. The project needs to be on the Pro plan or higher (Edit: For using "Login As" for app preview, you only need the Standard Plan)